# dynamically created query in APEX and Update the Value

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, loop

Dynamically created query in APEX and Update the Value. Trying to update field value by

```
   string objectName = 'Account';
   list<sobject> recordsList;
   string condition = 'id IN:' + recId;
   string query = 'select id, ownerId from ' + objectName + ' Where '+ condition;
   recordsList = Database.query(query);  
   List<sobject> objectlist = new List<sobject>();
       for(sobject obj: recordsList){
           system.debug(obj.get('ownerId'));
            obj.put('ownerId', owner);
             objectlist.add(obj);
       }
   Update objectlist;
```

Getting below compiler error `Variable does not exist: ownerId`. Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: This is the offending line `obj.put(ownerId, owner);`. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, put if you want to set the owner id for the object to some value you should use `obj.put('OwnerId', newOwnerId);`. Note that in your case, both `ownerId` and `owner` are non-existent (in the snippet at least).

Comment: You might want to try using "objectName.OwnerId" in the SOQL, and check if it fits with your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but there were a few things to fix.

First: There was no `owner` defined anywhere in your code. Perhaps you have it defined somewhere else above this snippet.

Second, you need to either name the bind variable like `... WHERE Id IN: varName` OR just put the value in: `... WHERE Id = \'0010500000XxxxXXXX\'`

Thirdly, the ownerId needs to be a list if you use `IN`

Below is a code snippet with these issues fixed - that I can verify works (Id obfuscated).

```
    String[] recIds =  new String[]{'0010500000XxxxXXXX'};
    String objectName = 'Account';
    List<SObject> recordsList;
    String condition = 'Id IN :recIds' ;
    String query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE ' + condition + ' LIMIT 2 ';
    recordsList = Database.query(query);  
    List<SObject> objectlist = new List<SObject>();
       for(SObject obj: recordsList){
           System.debug(obj.get('OwnerId'));
           obj.put('OwnerId', obj.get('OwnerId'));
           objectlist.add(obj);
       }
   update objectlist;
```